# Preferences Android - Default values: XML or programmatically?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-preferences, android-settings

I have a field on settings where you can change the name of your device, i.e., the name that the other devices will see from that app. For the first use of this app, I would like to put on that field the model of the mobile phone (e.g. `Build.MODEL`) and keep that value until it is modified by the user. My question is: is it possible to set this kind of value from XML or can you do it programmatically? Assuming last case, how can you do it? I have checked other posts but I do not understand how `EditTextPreference.setDefaultValue` works.

Of course I know the field `android:defaultValue` in `EditTextPreference`, but I am not sure if it possible to set the model of the device from there.